# Dynamically arranged html components the angular way

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates

I'm on a new project in a really nice environment *sigh* ...
I'm the FE-Architect/Lead, and as the designs aren't ready yet, I'm doing rather **generic stuff** atm.

Basically while pondering things - especially my own Auto-Wiring-Mechanism - it came to mind that I need **some Service that will assemble my stateful App** into the localStorage-saved state: Take the Controllers/Directives that have been saved to localStorage and assemble the page.

I'm coming from a different framework originally and/or tend to think not exactly **angularish** sometimes. So it turns out, ohhh, **non-trivial** here, and it came as a surprise.
*Nice* surprise of course, as in terms of challenge :)

So, **what I'm looking for** can do the following:

- Arrange/Position/Instanciate Directives/HTML without absolute positioning/keeping HTMLs positioning mechanisms intact.
- Being able to drive this Behaviour via the service from the Main/Nav-Controller

I was thinking there might be some kind of nested ng-if setup, but it deems me to be the infinity loop/indefinite recursion route and anyway, *not elegent* and *surely not the  angular way*.

You can **understand the problem at hand** better *by example* hopefully:
Imagine you got a dashboard for your app. On that Dashboard you want a customizable set of widgets. *How in the heavens* would the angular way be to accomplish that?? It's so not angular to manipulate the DOM directly, but pray say, **is there some kind of *META-DIRECTIVE*** I can use for dynamic templating?

*ANY* rather smart/elegant suggestions very welcome :)

Cheers, Joehannes

Comment: sorry, it is a duplicate, didn't look carefully!

Comment: Duplicates are sometimes a good thing. I'm a backend C++ dev and completely new to MVC / MVVM / MVW, even more so Angular. I read the linked duplicate already, but it wasn't clear to me whether that was my question too. It's only when I read your example about a dashboard and widgets that I went, "A-ha! Yes, that _is_ exactly what I'm trying to do." Duplicates provide alternative representations that can be useful for beginners. I'm glad you asked again.